# Prove sequence is monotically decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, induction, monotone-functions

I've the following sequence: 
$b_{n+1}=b_{n}-\frac{1}{2n+2}+\frac{1}{2n+3}$ with $b_{1}=\frac{5}{6}$. I need to show this is a monotonic decreasing sequence, so $b_{n}>b_{n+1}$. I think I should use induction, thus:

**basis**: $b_{1}=\frac{5}{6}$ and $b_{2}=\frac{47}{60}$ thus $b_{1}>b_{2}$, it holds.

**hypothesis**: if $b_{n}>b_{n+1}$ then it follows that $b_{n+2}>b_{n+1}$.

**Proof**: Assume $b_{n}>b_{n+1}$. And this is where I'm stuck. How do I get from here to $b_{n+2}>b_{n+1}$?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: But you already proved it there yourself : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2535506/prove-that-a-sequence-is-bounded/2535657#2535657

Comment: I thought I did but I rechecked my induction and found it wasn't valid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use induction just write out $b_{n+1}<b_n$ which is equivalent with $$b_n-\frac1{2n+2}+\frac1{2n+3}<b_n\\\frac{1}{2n+2}>\frac{1}{2n+3}$$
Which is true.

Comment: but is this mathematically sound for a proof?

Comment: @Mathbeginner Yes, you picked a arbitrary $n$ and deduced that $b_n>b_{n+1}$ hence it works for all $n$ for which $\frac1{2n+2}>\frac1{2n+3}$.

Answer (score 0):

$b_{n+1}-b_n=\dfrac{-1}{2n+2}+\dfrac{1}{2n+3}=\dfrac{-(2n+3)+(2n+2)}{(2n+2)(2n+3)}=\dfrac{-1}{(2n+2)(2n+3)}<0$

So $b_{n+1}<b_n$, you just need to add the two fractions, numerator is negative and denominator is positive, so overall a negative number.

There is no need for induction, since this is valid for any $n$.